Custom rounded shape CSS
I'm trying to draw a custom shape with rounded corners using CSS. Below is an image of what I have so far, but as you can see the rounded corners aren't completely working.
Attempt at custom shape
I've tried using SVGs but haven't been able to get that work work yet. Here is the code for the shape below:
.custom-shape {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0 100%);
    border-radius: 10px;
}


Polygons don't have curves... you need a path.

You could use two rectangle with a css skew on the second to achieve it, i've made the two rectangle with different color so that you can understand but if you put them both like this you can create your shape.
Here is my code :


  .shape-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 90vh;
    }
    
    .shape-container .rec {
      height: 500px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .shape-container .rec::after {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 20px;
      transform: skew(-11deg) translateX(20%);
    }
    <div class="shape-container">
      <div class="rec"></div>
    </div>


  



If you want to change the angle of the right side just play with the skew value.

Thank you! Using an :afterelement make simple shape easily customisable and fast to do so, it also easier on the browser and more consistent on every browser then a long clip path but it for sure not good to do anything too complexe but since my code is an :after element relative to his parent, it make it responsive, if you want to keep the ratio the same, use aspect-ratio or a width using the vh unit with a set min-width to limit any problem. Thank you @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz for your support you've made my day! PS : sorry for my bad english!

You need to define the exact shape that you need. And if you would like rounded corners, you need to draw them. You can use any SVG or text editor to draw a shape. In this example I use the shape path() because I have been drawing a path in SvgPathEditor.


div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  clip-path: path('M 30 0 A 30 30 90 0 0 0 30 V 270 A 30 30 90 0 0 30 300 H 210 A 42 30 90 0 0 240 270 L 300 30 A 30 25.5 0 0 0 270 0 Z');
}
<div></div>




It looks nice. But then you need to take the help of an app of software for this. I think there should also be a simple solution for this.

@RajKumar You can always create an SVG path or polygon "by hand", on paper or in a text editor. That is as simple as it can get, but sometimes an SVG editor can be helpful .

This is close... one thing I forgot to mention in my post is I need the height of the shape to adjust to it's parent height. Is there a way to achieve this with path()?

@twag123 a dynamic height complicates things. As the spec says, clip-path uses a basic shape. It depends or shape of the thing. If we just ignore the fact that we need some CSS property or some kind of SVG/SVG element. You would like rounded corners (and maintain the aspect ration of the corner I assume) and a scaling the height. With the asymmetric form (slanted right line), that is impossible, because the angle of top right and bottom right corner changes. In a simpler use case we could use a sliding door technique or some scaling in an SVG image.
